# excel adding a discount in excel but with a maximum amount

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have got a price column and a discount price column.

To add a 10 percent discount, I have to add one column for calculating the discount amount and other for minus that amounts from the original price.

for the calculating discount amount column right now, it it is

=AD2/10 (the original price divided by 10) for 10%

I want to do 10% discount but with a maximum discount of 5.00 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the excel Min function, in the screenshot below the formalua in B3 is

```
=Min(A3/2; 2)
```

Which will give you the smallest of the two values

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-61635D12-920F-4CE2-A70F-96F202DCC152

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is throwing a incorrect syntax error throwing an error based on ";" however it asks to change it to ":" which just heighlights a bunch of irrelevant rows

Comment: You may need to use , (comma) instead based on your locale settings

Answer (score 0):

you can use the IF-function. 
Like if the dicount is smaller than 5, use discount else use 5.

```
=IF(A2*$D$2<5;A2*$D$2;5)
```

[image]

Comment: "the forumula you typed contains an error" appears.

Comment: Sorry, I m not good with error handling in excel. But do you understand the function and can apply it to your system, instead of copy pasting it?